# Access SQL into PowerQuery SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, powerquery

I have build a query/ table in access some time ago.
I would like to get the same one in Excel/ PowerQuery.

The original code looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    MAIN_V02_N.ABLITM, 
    MAIN_V01_N.ACDSC1, 
    MAIN_V02_N.ABSRP0 AS Line, 
    MAIN_V02_N.ABPRP4 AS wheel, 
    MAIN_V01_N.ACUOM1, 
    MAIN_V02_N.ABSTKT, 
    MAIN_V02_N.ABMCU, 
    MAIN_V02_N.ABRQMX AS Batchsize, 
    MAIN_V02_N.ABLTLV AS LT, 
    [UMCONV]/10000000 AS Boxsize, 
    V_MES_POOL_LDV002.UMUM
FROM 
    V_MES_POOL_LDV002 
        RIGHT JOIN 
    (MAIN_V02_N 
        LEFT JOIN 
    MAIN_V01_N 
        ON 
    MAIN_V02_N.ABLITM = MAIN_V01_N.ACLITM) 
        ON 
    V_MES_POOL_LDV002.UMITM = MAIN_V02_N.ABITM
WHERE 
    (((MAIN_V02_N.ABSTKT)="M") 
        AND 
    ((MAIN_V02_N.ABMCU)="        TEG" 
        Or 
    (MAIN_V02_N.ABMCU)="        TEP" 
        Or 
    (MAIN_V02_N.ABMCU)="        TEF") 
        AND 
    ((V_MES_POOL_LDV002.UMUM)="BX" 
        Or 
    (V_MES_POOL_LDV002.UMUM)="RE" 
        Or 
    (V_MES_POOL_LDV002.UMUM)="CN")) 
        OR 
    (((MAIN_V02_N.ABSRP0) Like "N*") 
        AND 
    ((MAIN_V02_N.ABSTKT)="M") 
        AND 
    ((MAIN_V02_N.ABMCU)="        TEP"))
ORDER BY 
    MAIN_V02_N.ABLITM;
```

The database is an Oracle.

I get always the error the SQL is not appropriate.

Does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace " for '. It should work.